# Замена на map vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет,как будет выглядеть функция ,если заменить на map?

```
getPower (state) {
      const ar = [];
      state.contracts.forEach(el => {
        ar.push(el.car.manufactureYear)
      });
      return ar
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не нужно обращение к this то можно еще короче

```js
getPower: state =>
  state.contracts.map(el =>
    el.car.manufactureYear
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getPower (state) {
  return state.contracts.map(el =>
    el.car.manufactureYear
  );
}
```